# jQuery css method not working inside toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement jQuery toggle. This is my code:

The addClass and removeClass works fine But all of the margin CSS not working. How can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu_pc").click(function() {
    $('.sidebar_pc').toggle(0, function() {
      $(".pusher_pc").css('margin-left', '4px');
      $(".sidebar_pc").removeClass("visible");
    }, function() {
      $(".sidebar_pc").addClass("visible");
      $(".pusher_pc").css('margin-left', "250px");
      $(".sidebar_pc").css('margin-top', "64px");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui visible left sidebar inverted vertical menu overlay sidebar_pc" style="margin-top:64px !important; width: 240px;">
  <div style="margin-top:10%; color:white;">
    <center>
      <img class="ui circular image" height="70px" src="https://www.tsafindia.org/assets/images/signin.png" style="margin-top:2%" width="70px">
      <h4>{{person.username}}<br> {{person.email}}
      </h4>
    </center>
  </div><br>
  <hr style="margin-bottom:2px;"> {% if person.role == "pengajuevent" %} <a class="item" href="/"><i class="calendar icon"></i> Kalender Event</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event"><i class="time icon"></i> Pengajuan Event</a> <a class="item hide_1" href="/logout"><i class="log out icon"></i> Log Out</a>  {% endif %} {% if person.role == "tatausaha" %} <a class="item" href="/"><i class="calendar icon"></i> Kalender Event</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event/verifikasi"><i class="time icon"></i> Verifikasi Event {% if person.notif &gt; 0 %}
              <div class="ui red label">
                <i class="alarm icon"></i> {{person.notif}}
              </div>{% endif %}</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event"><i class="time icon"></i> Pengajuan Event</a> <a class="item hide_1" href="/logout"><i class="log out icon"></i> Log Out</a> {% endif %} {% if person.role == "dekan" %} <a class="item"
    href="/"><i class="calendar icon"></i> Kalender Event</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event/verifikasi"><i class="time icon"></i> Verifikasi Event {% if person.notif &gt; 0 %}
              <div class="ui red label">
                <i class="alarm icon"></i> {{person.notif}}
              </div>{% endif %}</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event"><i class="time icon"></i> Pengajuan Event</a> <a class="item hide_1" href="/logout"><i class="log out icon"></i> Log Out</a> {% endif %} {% if person.role == "wd2" %} <a class="item"
    href="/"><i class="calendar icon"></i> Kalender Event</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event/verifikasi"><i class="time icon"></i> Verifikasi Event {% if person.notif &gt; 0 %}
              <div class="ui red label">
                <i class="alarm icon"></i> {{person.notif}}
              </div>{% endif %}</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event"><i class="time icon"></i> Pengajuan Event</a> <a class="item hide_1" href="/logout"><i class="log out icon"></i> Log Out</a> {% endif %} {% if person.role == "superadmin" %}
  <a
    class="item" href="/"><i class="calendar icon"></i> Kalender Event</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_event"><i class="time icon"></i> Pengajuan Event</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_venue"><i class="home icon"></i> Manajemen List Venue</a>
    <a class="item" href="/manajemen_list_email"><i class="mail icon"></i> Manajemen List Email</a> <a class="item" href="/manajemen_list_akun"><i class="user icon"></i> Manajemen List Akun</a> <a class="item hide_1" href="/logout"><i class="log out icon"></i> Log Out</a> {% endif %}
</div>

<div class="pusher_pc">

  {% block content %}
  <!-- include another html documents -->

  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see the associated HTML and CSS code in order to help you. Note that you only ever set the `margin-top` on `.sidebar_pc`, you never change it

Comment: I can't find any element in your html with the class menu_pc

Comment: sorry the html code is messy

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i implement that button in top attached menu instead of the side menu

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen is there no problem with my jquery syntax?

Comment: Please have a look at the snippet I made - replace all the template with enough rendered HTML to create a [mcve]

Comment: Why not put the margins in the CSS for the classes you toggle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you wanted to do. But here an example of how you can manually trigger a toggle and execute any code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggle = 0;
  $(".menu_pc").click(function() {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(toggle){
      $(".pusher_pc").css('margin-left', '0');
      $(".sidebar_pc").removeClass("visible");
    }else {
      $(".sidebar_pc").addClass("visible");
      $(".pusher_pc").css('margin-left', "250px");
      $(".sidebar_pc").css('margin-top', "64px");
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_pc{
  display:inline-block;
  //width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar_pc, .pusher_pc{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 64px;
  background: #111;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.pusher_pc{
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <div class="menu_pc">Click me</div>
  <div>
    <div class="pusher_pc">Pusher</div>
    <div class="sidebar_pc">Sidebar</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer Lasithds. I really appreciate it. But i have found the solution yet. By using the toggleclass method. Here is the code:       

$( ".menu_pc" ).click(function() {
  $('.sidebar_pc').toggleClass("visible");
  $('div.pusher_pc').toggleClass("pusher_default");
});

Comment: But then you can't do other stuff such as changing the margin etc. using your method. How is it solving your problem?

Comment: $('div.pusher_pc').toggleClass("pusher_default"); this code change my margin when my sidebar changed

Comment: Your initial question was to change the margin and class both